# Merge dataset on corresponding column values in R

Tags: r, merge, dataset

Dataset1

```
 Ordernumbers   column1   column2   column3
1. 523542          x         x       x
2. 474822          x         x       x
3. 456453          x         x       x
4. 124132
5. 342142
6. 342122
7. 432522
8. 432134
9. 234234
```

Dataset2

```
transformantID   columnA   columnB   columnC
1. 124132         x         x       x
2. 234234         x         x       x
3. 342142         x         x       x
4. 474822
5. 523542         y         w       z  
6. 432522
7. 456453
```

My goal is to merge these two dataframes. The column "ordernumber" from dataset1 matches vlaues with values from the column "transformantID" from dataset 2. I would like to include all rows from dataset2 in dataset1 so transformantID value matches the ordernumber value like so:

```
Ordernumbers   column1   column2   column3  columnA   columnB   columnC
1. 523542          x         x       x        y         w         z
```

And have this done for every row in the first dataset. The number of rows from dataset1 exceed those of dataset2.

Comment: Have you looked at `?merge` (like in your title)?

Comment: Also, please try Google next time, for example "*merge in r*" will give you all you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge( Dataset1 , Dataset2 , by.x = "Ordernumbers" , by.y = "transformantID" )
```

Comment: Don't forget `all.x = TRUE`. Though it is generally not a good practice answering major dupes. Especially which could easily Googled using the title OP himself named his question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg looks like OP wants an inner join?

Comment: From what I read "*I would like to include all rows from dataset2 in dataset1*" sounds like left join to me, but I may be wrong

Comment: Though due the fact you are giving bounties all around, I understand you desperately need some rep, so (+1) ;)

Comment: hahahaha i am _thiiiis close_ to creating a tag in your honor